# Overview of basic results on cardinal arithmetic

Tags: reference-request, elementary-set-theory, cardinals, online-resources

Are there some good overviews of basic formulas about addition, multiplication and exponentiation of cardinals (preferably available online)?

Comment: I have a sequence of blog posts on this topic. It starts here: http://caicedoteaching.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/580-ii-cardinal-arithmetic/

Comment: And perhaps the most efficient way of looking at all the relevant posts is to go to http://caicedoteaching.wordpress.com/ and then select category 580 (and scroll down).

Comment: [Pete Clark](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/299/pete-l-clark) has some stuff written up in his [website](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/expositions2012.html) under "Set Theory". Chapter 2 gives the basics.

Answer (score 104):

$\newcommand{\alnul}{\aleph_0}\newcommand{\mfr}[1]{\mathfrak{#1}}\newcommand{\Ra}{\Rightarrow}\newcommand{\card}[1]{\left|#1\right|}\newcommand{\powerset}[1]{\mathcal P(#1)}\newcommand{\Lra}{\Leftrightarrow}\newcommand{\Zobr}[3]{#1\colon#2\to#3}$I have no doubt that you there are many useful online resources for these, but many such identities are available here at MSE, together with their proofs.

I'll give a list of some basic results on cardinal arithmetics and I'll add links to results, which have proofs here at MSE. I am making this CW, so feel free to add more identities and pointers to further useful questions and answers.

In the identities below, $a$, $b$, $c$ denote arbitrary cardinals, $X$ is an arbitrary set, $\alnul$ is the cardinality of $\mathbb N$ and $\mfr c=2^{\alnul}$. Cardinality of a set $X$ is denoted by $\card X$ and $\powerset X$ is the notation of the power set of $X$.

Equality of cardinal numbers is defined as follows:
$$|A|=|B| \Lra \text{ there exists a bijection }\Zobr fAB.$$
Inequality of cardinal numbers is defined as follows:
$$|A|\le|B| \Lra \text{ there exists an injective function }\Zobr fAB.$$
The definitions of the operations on cardinal numbers (addition, multiplication, exponentiation) can be found e.g. in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/89428/).

Validity of Axiom of Choice is assumed. If you want to learn about cardinals without AC, you can have a look e.g. at this question: [Defining cardinality in the absence of choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53770/defining-cardinality-in-the-absence-of-choice/)

> - $a\le b$ $\land$ $b\le c$ $\Ra$ $a\le c$

This follows from the fact that composition of two injective maps is injective

> - $a\le b \land b\le a \Ra a=b$

This result is known as [Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem). (Also called Cantor–Bernstein theorem or Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein theorem.)

> If $A$ and $B$ are sets such that $|A|\le |B|$ and $|B|\le|A|$, then $|A|=|B|$.

The following results says that for any two sets the cardinalities are comparable.

> - For any two sets $A$, $B$ we have $|A|\le|B|$ $\lor$ $|B|\le|A|$. I.e. any two sets/any two cardinal numbers are comparable.

Note: Proof of this result uses the [Axiom of Choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice), but it is not required. For the role of AC in this result see here: [Is the class of cardinals totally ordered?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69774/is-the-class-of-cardinals-totally-ordered/) and [For any two sets $A,B$ , $|A|\leq|B|$ or $|B|\leq|A|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268942/for-any-two-sets-a-b-a-leqb-or-b-leqa) and [Proving $(A\le B)\vee (B\le A)$ for sets $A$ and $B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421638/proving-a-le-b-vee-b-le-a-for-sets-a-and-b).

> - $|A|\le|B| \Lra (\text{there exists a surjective function }\Zobr fBA \text{ or $A$ is empty}).$

[There exists an injection from $X$ to $Y$ if and only if there exists a surjection from $Y$ to $X$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192460/there-exists-an-injection-from-x-to-y-if-and-only-if-there-exists-a-surjecti)

Note: Proof of this result uses the [Axiom of Choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice).

> - $\card{\powerset X}=2^{\card X}$

See e.g. [How to show equinumerosity of  the powerset of $A$ and the set of functions from $A$ to $\{0,1\}$ without cardinal arithmetic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41006/how-to-show-equinumerosity-of-the-powerset-of-a-and-the-set-of-functions-from) or [Finding a correspondence between $\{0,1\}^A$ and $\mathcal P(A)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84180/finding-a-correspondence-between-two-sets) or [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/129303/). The question
[What is the set of all functions from $\{0, 1\}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ equinumerous to?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51059/what-is-the-set-of-all-functions-from-0-1-to-mathbbn-equinumerous-to) deals with a special case, but it can be easily generalized.

> - $a+b=b+a$

This follows simply from commutativity of union: $A\cup B=B\cup A$.

> - $a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c$

This follows from associativity of union: $A\cup(B\cup C)=(A\cup B)\cup C$.

> - $b\le c \Ra a+b\le a+c$

This is (after adding some details) basically the same thing as the implication $B\subseteq C$ $\Ra$ $A\cup B\subseteq A\cup C$. See [Does $a \le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$ for cardinal numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598668/does-a-le-b-imply-ac-le-bc-for-cardinal-numbers)

> - $ab=ba$

A bijection $A\times B\to B\times A$ can be given by $(x,y)\mapsto (y,x)$.

> - $a(bc)=(ab)c$

A bijection between $A\times(B\times C)$ and $(A\times B)\times C$ can be given by $(x,(y,z))\mapsto ((x,y),z)$. See here: [A bijection between $X \times (Y \times Z)$ and $ (X \times Y) \times Z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605763/a-bijection-between-x-times-y-times-z-and-x-times-y-times-z)

> - $a(b+c)=ab+ac$

This follows from the fact that $A\times(B\cup C)=A\times B\cup A\times C$.

> - $b\le c \Ra  ab\le ac$

See e.g. [Proof of cardinality inequality: $m_1\le m_2$, $k_1\le k_2$ implies $k_1m_1\le k_2m_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57236/proof-of-cardinality-inequality) or [Will $\kappa_1, \kappa_2, m$ cardinals. Given $\kappa_1 \leq \kappa_2$. prove: $\kappa_1 \cdot m \leq \kappa_2 \cdot m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391880/will-kappa-1-kappa-2-m-cardinals-given-kappa-1-leq-kappa-2-prove)

> - $a^2=a\cdot a$

See e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/129303/)

> - $a\le b \Ra a^c\le b^c$

See e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/57393/).

> - $a\le b \land c\ne 0 \Ra c^a\le c^b$

See e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854509).

Note that this is not true for $c=0$, since $0^0=1$. (The set $\emptyset^\emptyset=\{\emptyset\}$ has one element.) The set $\emptyset^\emptyset$ and its cardinality is also discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11771/why-is-y-emptyset-1-but-emptysety-0-where-y-neq-emptyset).

> - $a^{b+c}=a^b\cdot a^c$

See e.g. [Let $A,B,C$ be sets, and $B \cap C=\emptyset$. Show $|A^{B \cup C}|=|A^B \times A^C|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842444/let-a-b-c-be-sets-and-b-cap-c-emptyset-show-ab-cup-c-ab-times) and [Notation on proving injectivity of a function $f:A^{B\;\cup\; C}\to A^B\times A^C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80105/notation-on-proving-injectivity-of-a-function-fab-cup-c-to-ab-times-a).

> - $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$

See e.g. [How to show $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ for arbitrary cardinal numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57398/how-to-show-abc-abc-for-arbitrary-cardinal-numbers)

> - $(ab)^c=a^c\cdot b^c$

See e.g. [Equinumerousity of operations on cardinal numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1751288/equinumerousity-of-operations-on-cardinal-numbers) and [How to prove $|{^A}{(K \times L)}| =_c |{^A}{K} \times {^A}{L}|$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720386/how-to-prove-ak-times-l-c-ak-times-al)

> - $a^b\le 2^{ab}$

See e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/36969/)

> - $a<2^a$

This is [Cantor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem). The question [Is the class of subsets of integers countably infinite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61926/is-the-class-of-subsets-of-integers-countably-infinite) deals with the special case $a=\alnul$, but there are answers which discuss the more general result or can be easily generalized. See also [Understanding the proof for $ 2^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208987/understanding-the-proof-for-2-aleph-0-aleph-0/). This question asks about the general result: [Cardinality of a set A is strictly less than the cardinality of the power set of A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354556/cardinality-of-a-set-a-is-strictly-less-than-the-cardinality-of-the-power-set-of)

> - $\alnul+\alnul=\alnul$

See e.g. [Let $X$ and $Y$ be countable sets. Then $X\cup Y$ is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57479/let-x-and-y-be-countable-sets-then-x-cup-y-is-countable)

> - $a\ge\alnul \Ra \alnul+a=a$
> - $\alnul\cdot\alnul=\alnul$

See e.g. [Bijecting a countably infinite set $S$ and its cartesian product $S \times S$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16611/bijecting-a-countably-infinite-set-s-and-its-cartesian-product-s-times-s), [How does one get the formula for this bijection from $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ onto $\mathbb{N}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29420/how-does-one-get-the-formula-for-this-bijection-from-mathbbn-times-mathbbn),
[The cartesian product $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54158/the-cartesian-product-mathbbn-times-mathbbn-is-countable) and [Proving the Cantor Pairing Function Bijective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91318/proving-the-cantor-pairing-function-bijective)

The following result is, to some extent, related to the following:

> - Union of countably many countable sets is countable.

It is worth mentioning that proof of this uses Axiom of Choice. See [Prove that the union of countably many countable sets is countable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603456/prove-that-the-union-of-countably-many-countable-sets-is-countable)

> - $\alnul^{\alnul}=2^{\alnul}=\mfr c$

See e.g. [Is $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ smaller than or equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110211/is-aleph-0-aleph-0-smaller-than-or-equal-to-2-aleph-0) or [What is $\aleph_0$ powered to $\aleph_0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183513/what-is-aleph-0-powered-to-aleph-0) or [What's the cardinality of all sequences with coefficients in an infinite set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14429/whats-the-cardinality-of-all-sequences-with-coefficients-in-an-infinite-set) (One of the answers to this question also discusses powers of the form $\aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_\beta}$ in general.

> - If $a$ is infinite cardinal, then $a^2=a$.

See e.g. [About a paper of Zermelo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54892/about-a-paper-of-zermelo/)

Note: Proof of this result uses the [Axiom of Choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice). See also: [For every infinite $S$, $|S|=|S\times S|$ implies the Axiom of choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56466/for-every-infinite-s-s-s-times-s-implies-the-axiom-of-choice)

> - If $b$, $c$ are infinite cardinals, then $b+c=bc=\max\{b,c\}$.

See e.g. [How to prove that from "Every infinite cardinal satisfies $a^2=a$" we can prove that $b+c=bc$ for any two infinite cardinals $b,c$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48828/simple-cardinal-arithmetic)

Note: This is a consequence of the preceding result, so it relies on the Axiom of Choice too.

Comment: I've posted a question at meta about the format of answer I've chosen here. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967/would-organizer-posts-be-useful-wellcome-here

Comment: Do you think that you should mention the use of the axiom of choice, or at least which results holds without it?

Comment: @Asaf: I've added a note mentioning AC. (The last two are the only identities from the list that use AC, right?) To be honest, I am not completely sure about the usual definition of
_cardinal_ and _cardinality_ when we do not assume AC. I should probably read one of your answers on this topic. ;-)

Comment: BTW I was a little surprised that I did not find the proof of $a^2=a$ here. (Maybe we don't have it here, maybe it is somewhere but I did not find it.)

Comment: I wrote that proof: [$a^2=a$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54892/about-a-paper-of-zermelo/54904#54904). Cardinals without choice: [Defining cardinality](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53770/defining-cardinality-in-the-absence-of-choice/53771#53771).

Comment: You have set the bar high for future "Overview" questions!

Comment: Comparability of cardinals (which, like $a^2=a$, is equivalent to choice) should be here, assuming there's something on math.se to link to.

Comment: Good catch @Chris; thanks. I've added some more stuff about inequality of cardinal numbers and if I find corresponding questions, I'll add links to them, too. I made the question CW, so feel free to improve it.

Comment: Martin, there was a question whether the cardinals are totally ordered. It should be enough to answer Chris' request. I recall that we both answered and yours was accepted.

Comment: @Asaf You mean [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69774/is-the-class-of-cardinals-totally-ordered/). The question is more about whether AC is needed for this result, so I've added it to the part about AC.

Comment: Yes. I think that the post can use a reorganization somehow. One day I will sit and do that.

Comment: @Martin: Do you think it might be time for a good revision and addition to this page? I've seen a lot of questions being re-asked (and in some the answers are superior to previous answers).

Comment: @Asaf Feel free to make any improvements you find useful.

Comment: Hi, I'm just here to say this answer is really good, obvious +1.

Comment: If $a_i\lt b_i$ for $i\in I$ then $\sum_{i\in I}a_i\lt\prod_{i\in I}b_i$.