# There exist a surjection from X to Y and a surjection from Y to X iff there exists a bijection betwen X and Y.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Theorem: Let X and Y bet non empty sets, then there exist a surjection from X to Y and a surjection from Y to X if and only if there exist a bijection betwen X and Y.

Do anyone have an idea how to prove this?

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof of this is actually quite involved. First, we need the **Partition Principle**:

> If there exists a surjection from $Y$ onto $X$ then there exists an injection from $X$ into $Y$.

The proof of this fact relies on the axiom of choice. You can refer to a [previous stack exchange thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192460/there-exists-an-injection-from-x-to-y-if-and-only-if-there-exists-a-surjecti) for the details. From here, we now have two *injections*, $h:X\to Y$ and $k: Y\to X$. The problem of finding a bijection is now reduced to the well-known Cantor-Bernstein theorem, whose proof also is quite lengthy. You can refer [here](https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cantor-Bernstein-Schr%C3%B6der_Theorem) for a few different methods. Taken together, this result is called the "Dual Cantor-Berstein Theorem."