# Prove if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is surjective then $|X|\ge|Y|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Prove if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is surjective then $|X|\ge|Y|$

**My work:**

Let $X,Y$ sets.

Suppose $|X|\leq |Y|$ then exists a function $g:X\rightarrow Y$ injective.

Here I'm stuck, can someone help me?

Comment: The conclusion of the implication should be $|X|\ge |Y|$ not $|X|>|Y|$

Comment: true, thanks @AtifFarooq

Comment: See also: [There exists an injection from $X$ to $Y$ if and only if there exists a surjection from $Y$ to $X$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/192460) (and other posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/192460)).

Answer (score 4):

The statement is false. Given *any* set $X$, the identity from $X$ onto itself is surjective. However, it's not true that $|X|>|X|$.

Answer (score 2):

As remarked in the previous answer, you want $\geq$.

for each $y \in Y$, consider$f^{-1}(\{y\})$ and choose a unique $x$ in there. Taking the uniion of all these, there is a collection $U \subset X$ so that $f(U)=Y$, and is a biijection, so there is a bijection $g:Y \to U \subset X$