# If there is an surjection $f : \Bbb{Z}^+ \to a$, then there is an injection $f : a \to \Bbb{Z}^+$

Tags: functions, proof-writing, proof-explanation, set-theory

I am trying to prove the following:

> Suppose there is a surjection $f : \Bbb{Z}^+ \to a$ and $a \neq \varnothing$. How might we go about showing that there is an injection $h : a \to \Bbb{Z}^+$ without using the well-ordering principle (i.e. just relying on definitions of the relevant functions and maybe inverses)?

From the definition of a surjection, we know that for each $x \in a$ there exists some $n \in \Bbb{Z}^+$ such that $f(n) = x$. But now we need to show that (i) there exists a function $h : a \to \Bbb{Z}^+$ and that (ii) $h$ is injective, and it seems that we just can't get enough out of the definition of a surjection to prove either.

Do I need to make use of specific properties of $\Bbb{Z}^+$? I am at a loss here, and I wonder if anyone can help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by "the well-ordering principle"? I think no matter what you'll want to make use of the ordering on $\mathbb Z^+$, otherwise this does not work. (But you don't need to assume that $a$ has any sort of ordering.)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, drawing the injection constructively fundamentally requires the ordering of $\mathbb{Z}^+$. More generally one could say that for a well-ordered set $S$ and any nonempty set $A$, there is a surjection $f : S \to A$ iff there exists an injection $g: A \to S$. But in $\mathsf{ZF}$ [that's the best you can do](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/192486): without choice there may be sets $A, B$ for which there exists a surjection $f : A \to B$ but no injection $g : B \to A$.

For completeness' sake, let's construct the injection in the well-ordered version. Let $(S, \leq)$ be a well-ordered set, let $A$ be a nonempty set, and suppose we have a surjective function $f : S \to A$. Then for each $a \in A$, the set $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is nonempty. By well-ordering, the function $g : A \to S$ given by $g(a) = \min(f^{-1}(\{a\}))$ is therefore well-defined. We claim $g$ is injective.

Indeed, suppose $g(a_1) = g(a_2)$ for some $a_1, a_2 \in A$. Since clearly $g(a) \in f^{-1}(\{a\})$ for every $a \in A$, we simply apply $f$ and get
$$
a_1 = f(g(a_1)) = f(g(a_2)) = a_2.
$$
Hence $g$ is injective.

**Addendum:** By the way, when I say "the ordering of $\mathbb{Z}^+$" I don't mean to imply you *need* the standard ordering. Any well-ordering will do for the construction. I meant that you need to know that $\mathbb{Z}^+$ does *have* at least one well-ordering (and this would simply follow from its countability).

Comment: Nice Argument Indeed!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am Assuming $A$ is a set.There can be three cases $A$ is countable infinite in that case there exist a bijection. $A$ is uncountable then answer is No Just take $A=\mathbb{R}$ Third $A$ is countable  finite obviously then there must exist two elements in $Z^{+}$ that goes to same element A(By Pegion Hole Principle) so no injection.

Comment: If $A$ were uncountable, no surjection from $\mathbb{Z}^+$ would exist--no need to consider that case.

Comment: Okay but Op might not know right already he is writing a set is small small letters so , I am quiet suspicious about his notational perspective unless he or she is a applied math field person. That's why I explicitly mention it in my answer by an example.

Comment: You're probably right, although I have seen set theorists use lowercase letters for sets when there's no notion of "points"

Comment: Ah I see!!! Then okay!

Comment: Hi, I am using lower case letters because I am coming to set theory from the perspective of a first-order language – i.e. a language built on first-order predicate logic, and the constant symbols there are lowercase. So there's nothing suspicious going on there, although it's probably nicer to use upper case letters for sets for readability

Comment: I see no offense, It's correct according to that perspectives.Actually I don't know nothing about first order predicate logic.

Comment: Sorry for wrong English nothing in the above sentence should be replaced by anything.

Comment: Don't apologise I understood what you said