# Cardinality of a set A is strictly less than the cardinality of the power set of A

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, cardinals

I am trying to prove the following statement but have trouble  comprehending/going forward with some parts! Here is the statement:

> If $A$ is any set, then  $|A|$ $<$ $|P(A)|$

Here is what I have so far:

We need to show that there is an injection from $A$ to $P(A)$ but *not* a surjection.

A natural choice for an injection is the function $ f(x)$ $=$ $\{x \}$, which in plain English, takes any element $x$ (that is in $A$) and sends it to the one-element set $\{x \}$. Thus $f(x)$ is injective!

To show that there is no surjection, for the sake of contradiction, assume there is a surjection. Here is where I start to have trouble. Surjectivity means that every element of the co-domain is mapped to an element of the domain, correct? Consequently, in this particular case, we are "matching" *sets* (from $P(A)$) to *elements* (from $A$) right?

If the above is correct, my problem arises here. I am not sure how to prove that $f$ is not surjective. Unfortunately, I am easily confused by notation so please explain in English. 
Thank you in advance!! :)

Comment: This can be proved by contradiction. Take your bijective map and construct a "contradictory" set in power set such that it is absurd that there is a map from $A$.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you want here is the so-called [*diagonal argument*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument#General_sets). The idea is to show that no matter what function $f:A\to\wp(A)$ you look at, you can find a subset $S_f$ of $A$ that is not in the range of $f$. If you can do that, you’ve shown that there is no map of $A$ onto $\wp(A)$ and therefore certainly no bijection from $A$ to $\wp(A)$.

To build the set $S_f$, imagine that you could somehow go through the set $A$ one element at a time. You look at an element $a\in A$, and one of two things must be true: either $a\in f(a)$, or $a\notin f(a)$. (Remember, $f(a)$ is some subset of $A$, so it’s meaningful to ask whether that subset contains $a$.) Since we’re building the set $S_f$ to suit ourselves, we get to decide whether $a\in S_f$ or not, and we’ll decide in exactly the opposite way from the function $f$: if $a\notin f(a)$, we’ll put $a$ into $S_f$, and if $a\in f(a)$, we won’t put $a$ into $S_f$. After we’ve done this for each $a\in A$, our set $S_f$ will contain exactly those $a\in A$ such that $a\notin f(a)$:

$$S_f=\{a\in A:a\notin f(a)\}\;.$$

For each $a\in A$, therefore, the sets $S_f$ and $f(a)$ differ in how they treat $a$: if $a\in f(a)$, then $a\notin S_f$, and if $a\notin f(a)$, then $a\in S_f$.

That’s almost the entire argument: all you have to do to finish it off is explain why this ensures that for $S_f$ is not the set $f(a)$ for any $a\in A$ and why this implies that $S_f$ is not in the range of $f$ and hence that $f$ is not a surjection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I feel as though this is a stupid question, but how can $a$ not be an element of $f(a)$ ? Can you please provide an example of this?

Comment: @nicefella: Let $A=\{0,1\}$, and define $f:A\to\wp(A)$ by $f(0)=\{1\}$ and $f(1)=\varnothing$, for instance. Then $0\notin\{1\}=f(0)$, and certainly $1\notin\varnothing=f(1)$.

Answer (score 6):

The idea is to prove that any mapping from $A$ to $P(A)$ will miss certain subsets of $A$. Consider any mapping, say $\phi$ from $A$ to $P(A)$. Now look at the set $B$ defined as follows.
$$B = \{a \in A: a \notin \phi(a)\}$$ Clearly, $B \in P(A)$. Now can we find $b \in A$ such that $\phi(b) = B$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Assume you have a surjection, consider the set $$T:x\not \in f(x)$$ and claim that $T$ is not empty. How does this help?

Comment: $T$ can be empty; consider the function $ f : x \to \{ x \} $.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose that we had such a matching. Then, for every element $a\in A$, there is a subset $S_a$ of $A$ matched to it, so that every subset of $A$ occurs as $S_a$ for some $a$.

We have to show that this is impossible, by producing a set which is missed out.
We follow [Russel's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox).

Let $B$ consist of all those elements a of $A$ which do not lie in the subset they label:

$$B=\{a\in A\  |\  a\not\in A_a\}$$

Now, if we have a complete matching, then the subset $B$ must occur in the matching, that is, $B = S_b$ for some element $b \in A$, but this is impossible:

If $b\in S_b$, then by definition $b \not\in B$, while if $b \not\in S_b$, then $b \in B$; so the sets $B$ and $S_b$ differ at the element $b$ (one contains it, the other doesn’t) and cannot be equal. So the
proposed matching is not complete.

Comment: Copy and paste from your notes, eh? What's chapter 2, and how do we see it?

Comment: I'm inclined to give a +1 for boldness.