# Validity of Proof for the Size of a Set Being Smaller Than Its Power Set

Tags: cardinals

I am currently working on a proof regarding the cardinality of a set and its power set and would greatly appreciate some feedback and guidance.

Let $A$ be a set and let $P(A)$ denote its power set. I have defined a function $f: A \rightarrow P(A)$ such that $f(x) = \{x\}$ for every $x \in A$. It's clear that this function is injective.
However, I noticed that this function is not surjective. For instance, for any two distinct elements $x, y \in A$, the set $\{x, y\}$ is in $P(A)$, but there doesn't exist an element $z \in A$ such that $f(z) = \{x, y\}$. So the function $f$ is not onto $P(A)$.

From this, I infer that the cardinality of $A$ is less than the cardinality of $P(A)$. My reasoning is that if a function from $A$ to $P(A)$ is not onto, then $P(A)$ must contain more elements than $A$.

Here are my questions:

Is my argument valid thus far?
How should I formally conclude my argument? Is it sufficient to say that since no function from $A$ to $P(A)$ can be onto, the cardinality of $P(A)$ must be greater than the cardinality of $A$?

Thank you for your time and help in advance.

Comment: Your argument of "less" suggests existence of two distinct elements in $A$

Comment: A better justification for why $f$ is not surjective is that the empty set is in $P(A),$ but the empty is not in the image of $f,$ since every member of the image of $f$ has the form $\{x\},$ which is a set that contains *something*, rather than the empty set, which is a set that contains *nothing* /does not contain anything.

Comment: Just saying that there is *one* function $A\to P(A)$ which is not surjective does not mean that *every* function $A\to P(A)$ is not surjective. You basically need to prove the latter claim. Indeed, if *every* function $A\to P(A)$ is not surjective, then there is no injection $P(A)\to A$ (I suppose this is using the axiom of choice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is not valid.

You cannot conclude $|A|<|P(A)|$ by constructing an injective and not surjective map from $A$ to P(A). For example, $f(n)=2n$ is a map from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. It is injective and not surjective, but is $|\mathbb{Z}|<|\mathbb{Z}|$? Clearly not. It is only true when comparing the cardinality of finite sets. For infinite sets, the most useful method is to construct injective maps and use [Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem)

You have proved that $|A|\leq |P(A)|$ by constructing an injective map. To prove $|A|<|P(A)|$, you can suppose there exists a bijective map and try to get a contradiction. See [Cardinality of a set A is strictly less than the cardinality of the power set of A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354556/cardinality-of-a-set-a-is-strictly-less-than-the-cardinality-of-the-power-set-of)

Comment: I see. In fact this was an idea that came up when reading the proof of the cardinal it’s theorem you mentioned. Thank you!