# Prove that the union of countably many countable sets is countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I am doing some homework exercises and stumbled upon this question. I don't know where to start.

> Prove that the union of countably many countable sets is countable.

Just reading it confuses me.

Any hints or help is greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: Why isn't this closed as a duplicate?

Comment: i have read "a countable union of countable sets is countable". are they the same question? frankly, it's difficult for me to understand the meaning of the statement.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Let's start with a quick review of "countable". A set is countable if we can set up a 1-1 correspondence between the set and the natural numbers. As an example, let's take $\mathbb{Z}$, which consists of all the integers. Is $\mathbb Z$ countable?

It may seem uncountable if you pick a naive correspondence, say $1 \mapsto 1$, $2 \mapsto 2 ...$, which leaves all of the negative numbers unmapped. But if we organize the integers like this:

$$0$$
$$1, -1$$
$$2, -2$$
$$3, -3$$
$$...$$

We quickly see that there is a map that works. Map 1 to 0, 2 to 1, 3 to -1, 4 to 2, 5 to -2, etc. So given an element $x$ in $\mathbb Z$, we either have that $1 \mapsto x$ if $x=0$, $2x \mapsto x$ if $x > 0$, or $2|x|+1 \mapsto x$ if $x < 0$. So the integers are countable.

We proved this by finding a map between the integers and the natural numbers. So to show that the union of countably many sets is countable, we need to find a similar mapping. First, let's unpack "the union of countably many countable sets is countable":

1. "countable sets" pretty simple. If $S$ is in our set of sets, there's a 1-1 correspondence between elements of $S$ and $\mathbb N$.
2. "countably many countable sets" we have a 1-1 correspondence between $\mathbb N$ and the sets themselves. In other words, we can write the sets as $S_1$, $S_2$, $S_3$... Let's call the set of sets $\{S_n\}, n \in \mathbb N$.
3. "union of countably many countable sets is countable". There is a 1-1 mapping between the elements in $\mathbb N$ and the elements in $S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3 ...$

So how do we prove this? We need to find a correspondence, of course. Fortunately, there's a simple way to do this. Let $s_{nm}$ be the $mth$ element of $S_n$. We can do this because $S_n$ is by definition of the problem countable. We can write the elements of ALL the sets like this:

$$s_{11}, s_{12}, s_{13} ...$$
$$s_{21}, s_{22}, s_{23} ...$$
$$s_{31}, s_{32}, s_{33} ...$$
$$...$$

Now let $1 \mapsto s_{11}$, $2 \mapsto s_{12}$, $3 \mapsto s_{21}$, $4 \mapsto s_{13}$, etc. You might notice that if we cross out every element that we've mapped, we're crossing them out in diagonal lines. With $1$ we cross out the first diagonal, $2-3$ we cross out the second diagonal, $4-6$ the third diagonal, $7-10$ the fourth diagonal, etc. The $nth$ diagonal requires us to map $n$ elements to cross it out. Since we never "run out" of elements in $\mathbb N$, eventually given any diagonal we'll create a map to every element in it. Since obviously every element in $S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3 ...$ is in one of the diagonals, we've created a 1-1 map between $\mathbb N$ and the set of sets.

Let's extend this one step further. What if we made $s_{11} = 1/1$, $s_{12} = 1/2$, $s_{21} = 2/1$, etc? Then $S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3 ... = \mathbb Q^+$! This is how you prove that the rationals are countable. Well, the positive rationals anyway. Can you extend these proofs to show that the rationals are countable?

Comment: Thank you for your incredibly detailed explanation! I have a good understanding on how to prove what I need to now. Thanks!

Comment: I have to ask something about $S_1\cup S_2\cup S_3\cup\cdots=\mathbb Q^+$, though. Wouldn't that make $1\mapsto s_{ii}$, for all $i$? Except if we define that in $\mathbb Q^+$, $\frac{1}{1}\neq\frac{2}{2}\neq\frac{3}{3}\neq\cdots$. Just saying.

Comment: what if the sets are not disjoint? This mapping would not be 1-1. Ex. if $S_1=S_2$

Comment: @Hovercouch: thanks for the proof. I think my textbook uses a similar argument, but I'm confused about the last part of it. Do you mind giving it a look? https://imgur.com/a/02y4Q

Comment: Here are the relevant definitions: https://imgur.com/a/0FTvg

Comment: @ensbana I won't go into detail but the last part of your book says that if you subtracted all those positive integers that mapped to elements that have already been mapped to other positive integers (Remember that there were common elements between $E_n$) from the set of all positive integers, then you would be left with a subset of positive integers $T$ which would in one-one correspondence with $S$. Now this $T$ could be finite, which is why it says that $S$ is at most countable. But since the first set of the sequence, $E_1$ is infinite, $S$ is infinite and thus only countable.

Comment: @ensbana which book is that?

Comment: It's "Principle of Mathematical Analysis" by Walter Rudin.

Comment: @IntegrateThis skip over already seen elements. This is used in the classic diagonalization proof of countability of the rationals.

Comment: What if a given set $S_i$ is finite? Where is it mapped here, because there would exist an $s_{ik}$ which does not exist.

Comment: @qwr Why bother skipping over the elements that have already occured? To show it's countable it's sufficient to show there exists a surjection $\mathbb{N} \to \bigcup_{i=1}^{∞}S_i$ so even if it repeats, it doesn't really matter if it's injective or not, count those bad boys again!

Comment: I think of a snake that worms its way through each of those elements $$s_{ij}$$ starting with $$s_{11}$$ and moving in a zigzag path.

Answer (score 79):

@Hovercouch's answer is correct, but the presentation hides a really rather  important point that you ought probably to know about. Here it is:

> The argument depends on accepting (a weak version of) the Axiom of Choice!

Why so?

You are only given that each $S_i$ is *countable*. You aren't given up front a way of *counting* any particular $S_i$, so you need to choose a surjective function $f_i\colon \mathbb{N} \to S_i$ to do the counting (in @Hovercouch's notation, $f_m(n) = s_{mn}$). And, crucially, you need to choose such an $f_i$ countably many times (a choice for each $i$).

That's an infinite sequence of choices to make: and it's a version of the highly non-trivial Axiom of Choice that says, yep, it's legitimate to pretend we can do that.

Comment: But if $S_i$ is countable it means that there is surjection like this. So if there is such function why do we need additional axiom to pick it?

Comment: But there are lots of such surjections for any $S_i$: you need to select one for each $i$. Check out http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Countable_Union_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable where the use of choice or its equivalent is made explicit.

Comment: Can't we get rid of need for this axiom if we prove that $A \cup B$ for any two sets $A$ and $B$ and then by induction that it is true for any countable union?

Comment: @Trismegistos: The induction only proves it for every finite union. Not for infinite unions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you. That is quite subtle distinction I was not aware of. I thought that because I am proving something for all possible lengths (finite sums comprised of n elements) then I am also proving for sums of infinite (but countable) length because all possible lengths comprise set of all natural number. Now when I know it what I wrote feels very silly.

Comment: @Trismegistos: You can prove that for every finite length, $1+1+\ldots+1$ is finite. Does that mean that an infinite sum of $1$'s is finite? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes it clicks now. I wondered for many years why infinite sums are not commutative because I expected you can prove by induction that they are commutative. I suspect I somehow mixed potential with actual infinity.

Comment: In fact, there is a model of ZF in which the reals are a countable union of countable sets!

Answer (score 23):

> Lemma 1. The union of two countable sets is countable.

*Proof.* Let $A = \{a_n : n \in \mathbb N\}$ and $B = \{b_n : n \in \mathbb N\}$. Then we can define the sequence $(c_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ by
$$c_{2k} = a_k \quad\text{and}\quad c_{2k+1} = b_k$$
for every $k \in \mathbb N$. Now $A \cup B = \{c_n : n \in \mathbb N\}$ and since it is a infinite set then it is countable.

By Lemma 1 you can prove your proposition by induction on the number of sets of the family

> *Corollary.* The union of a finite family of countable sets is a countable set.

To prove for a infinite family you need the Axiom of choice.

Comment: you need to consider the possibility that $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$

Comment: Even if the two sets aren't disjoint, we have $A\subseteq A\cup B$ where $A$ is countable.

Answer (score 9):

Let $\{A_n\}$ be a countable collection of collection sets. Denote, $A=\cup_{n\in I} A_n$. Now for each $A_n$ define a injection $f_n:A_n\to \mathbb{N}$. Now define a function $f:A\to \mathbb{N}$ as follows, take $x\in A$. Suppose $i$ be the first such that $x\in A_i$. Now define $f(x)=2^i3^{f_i(x)}$. Clearly this is an injection. Now if $A$ is finite then done, if not then $im(f)$ is an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$. And it's again countable, so bijective to $\mathbb{N}$. Also, $A$ is bijective to $im(f)$, so, $A$ is bijective to $\mathbb{N}$, done.

Comment: This is slick ${}$

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, a set is countable if you can enumerate the elements without forgetting any. (Enumerating the same element twice doesn't matter.)

As you can enumerate the elements in the given sets, you can enumerate them taking the sets in a round-robin fashion, adding one more set on every round.

$1$ of $1$,

$2$ of $1$, $1$ of $2$,

$3$ of $1$, $2$ of $2$, $1$ of $3$,

$4$ of $1$, $3$ of $2$, $2$ of $3$, $1$ of $4$,

$...$

As you can check, no one is missing.

Comment: You didn't mention the AoC. Is there more to your choice of the word 'enumeration' .Enumeration Theory https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Enumeration

Comment: you don't need the AoC if you can name the items you are mapping to.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the assertion is that, if you have a countable collection of sets which are countable themselves, then the union of all elements in the collection is also countable. To demonstrate this, try writing the set of natural numbers as the union of countably many infinite disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ (and, for that, consider decomposing every natural number in its unique prime factorization)

Answer (score 2):

Your sets are $A_n$ for $n \ge 0 $, all of which are countable (i.e. in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$); you have to prove that the set $A = \bigcup_{n \ge 0} A_n$ is countable. One way is to construct an injection of A into $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} $, which you can do easily (if $f_0 : A_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is a bijection, then you can define $g_0(a) = (f_0(a), 0) $ for all $a \in A_0$, then consider $B_1 = A \setminus A_0$ and go on... be careful with the domains of definition!). After that, use the classic fact that there is a bijection between $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}$, for instance $(a,b) \mapsto 2^a(2b+1) - 1$, and conclude with Cantor-Bernstein theorem and the obvious fact that there exists an injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Using

The wiki [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set#Definition) for countable sets,
The axiom of countable choice,
The make-it-a-disjoint-union technique found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union),
The padding-if-necessary the index out to $\omega$ technique,
The prime integers form an infinite set,
The prime factorization theorem.

the problem is (eventually) reduced to observing that

$\quad U =\;\bigsqcup_{p \text{ is a prime}} \{p^n \mid n \ge 1\}$

is a subset of $\Bbb N$.

Note: When there are duplicates in the original sets you'll need to get the smallest index where the element occurs to define the injective mapping into $U$.