# What is the cardianlity of Z[x], the set of all polynomials with integer coefficients?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, cardinals

Apparently it's aleph null, but I really don't understand why or how to form a bijection between the two sets, Z[x] and Z.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that the set of polynomials with rational coefficients is countable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1574436/show-that-the-set-of-polynomials-with-rational-coefficients-is-countable)

Comment: A common error here is to forget that *polynomials* strictly have finitely many nonzero coefficients.  Do not confuse polynomials with *formal power series* which may have infinitely many nonzero coefficients.  These are similar but not the same objects.  Use what makes them different to your advantage.

Comment: In many cases , we do not establish the bijection to prove the countability , but argue with known properties of countable sets (for example when unions are again countable). The key is in fact that polynomials have FINITE many coefficients. This even makes the set of algebraic numbers countable !