# Problem about subsequence of uncountable sequence.

Tags: analysis

Let $(a_n )_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a real number sequence with $a_n\ne a_m$ if $n\ne m$.

(a) Show that : $\{(a_{k_n })_{n\in\mathbb{N}} : k_1 < k_2< \cdots\}$ is uncountable. $(a_{k_n })$ is subsequence of $(a_n)$

(b)Show that  $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\times\cdots=\{(i_1, i_2,\ldots) ∶ i_n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is uncountable.

$\mathbb{N}$ is natural number.

Hello, I study Analysis alone in another country not use English.

So, I'm limited to ask question around me.

Anyway, I have no clue what I should start to solve this problem (a)

In (b), I know that $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is countable. And I think that $\mathbb{N}\times(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})$ also be countable.

I have a question : Don't be that countable set $\times$ countable set is countable?

I'm so DISSY. Please hele me! T.T

Comment: Even a countable disjoint union of countable sets is still countable.

Comment: Can I ask why that is true?

Comment: The proof is a little complicated. Also, the axiom of choice is needed. I will try to find a reference. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603456/prove-that-the-union-of-countably-many-countable-sets-is-countable it is basically analogous to showing that the rationals are countable.

Comment: Oh thank you for your help! so isn't problem (b) true ?

Comment: @PinkPanther What does your comment have to do with the question? OP is talking about products not unions. Even a countable product of finite sets can very well be uncountable.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I'm gonna be hazy

Comment: Can I ask why that can be uncountable??

Comment: @PraterDarrius See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument

Comment: @PraterDarrius $2^{\aleph_0}$ is uncountable.  Think of representing the numbers in $[0,1)$ in binary.

Comment: @Klaus you are right, I read that wrongly. However, one can think of products as disjoint unions by for example $$\mathbb N\times\mathbb N=\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}\{n\}\times\mathbb N$$ although I agree that this is probably not helpful here... My apologies.

Comment: Everyone thanks so much... I'm so late since I study that link... I almost understand it!!