# is there any way to represent irrational numbers with a finite amount of integers?

Tags: irrational-numbers

I know that rational numbers can be represented with two integers $\frac{a}{b}$.
But is there any way to represent irrational numbers with an finite amount of integers?

My best guess is $\frac{a}{b} ^ \frac{c}{d}$.
it can represent any root of any number, but I don't know if it can represent things like $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [uncountably many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set) irrational numbers but there are only [countably many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) finite sets (or lists) of integers. So it is impossible to represent every irrational number using only finitely many integers.

Comment: Great minds [think alike](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4049406/75808) (also, in this case, normal minds like mine :))

Comment: @ClementC  Sure, but you must type faster than me! $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: but... if you take normal ways of representing irrational numbers (with infinite integers), it is a contably amount of integers, can a uncountably set of numbers (irrationals) be represented as a countably set of countably sets?

Comment: A countable union of countable sets is countable, e.g., see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603456/prove-that-the-union-of-countably-many-countable-sets-is-countable.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have an encoding scheme allowing you to express a subset $C\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ of real numbers using, for each, a finite number of integers. Then you have a bijection between $C$ and
$$
\cup_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{N}^k
$$
and since this is countable, then so is $C$. But the irrational numbers are uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

If ${\frac{a}{b}}^{\frac{c}{d}}=\sqrt{2}$ then $(\log{\frac{a}{b}})*{\frac{c}{d}}=\frac{log{2}}{2}$, which implies
$\frac{a}{b}=2, \frac{c}{d}=\frac{1}{2}$.

But if ${\frac{a}{b}}^{\frac{c}{d}}=\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ then $\frac{c}{d}=\sqrt{2}$, and we would have found a rational number equal to $\sqrt{2}$. This is impossible, consequently there is no solution for ${\frac{a}{b}}^{\frac{c}{d}}=\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ among the rational numbers and, more generally, there can be no way of writing every real number using only a finite number of rational numbers and operations.

Comment: The issue with this is that it doesn't address other possibles schemes of "writing a real number with a finite number of integers." You showed that for this scheme (rational to the rational) it doesn't work, but... one could then suggest another scheme.

Comment: following the same logic, $(\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}})^{\sqrt{2}}$ is not $(2^{1})^{1}$