# series of the countable union of countable sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let  $A_i \subset \mathbb{R}$ be countable for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$.
How can I proof that in the case of absolute convergence there holds
$$\sum_{x \in \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i} x= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{x \in A_i}x$$The statement is absolutely evident but I cant prove it exactly.

Comment: Hint: If $S$ is an unordered set the _definition_ of $\sum_{x\in S}x$ is $\sup_F\sum_{x\in F}x$, where $F$ runs over the finite subsets of $S$.

Comment: Simply arrange $A_1, A_2, $ into rows and then list elements of $\cup A_i$ as is described in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/603499
Then, consider finite sums of $\sum_{x \in \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i} x$ and prove that it converges to RHS.