# Is it true that $({\aleph_1})^{\aleph_0} = {\aleph_1}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Is it true that $({\aleph_1})^{\aleph_0} = {\aleph_1}$?

My scenario is as follows:

The cardinal number of $\mathbb R$ is $|\mathbb R|={\aleph_1}$ and the cardinal number of the Cartesian product of countable sets of real numbers $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times\ldots$ is $({\aleph_1})^{\aleph_0}$. I wonder whether $({\aleph_1})^{\aleph_0}$ is still ${\aleph_1}$？

Also, what is $({\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}$, the cardinal number of the Cartesian product of countable sets of natural numbers $\mathbb N \times\mathbb N \times\mathbb N \times\ldots$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. It is not *necessarily* true. And it is also not necessarily true that $|\Bbb R|=\aleph_1$, this is known as the Continuum Hypothesis, and it is not provable nor refutable from the usual axioms of set theory.

Note that $2\leq\aleph_1\leq2^{\aleph_0}$, and therefore $2^{\aleph_0}\leq\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}\leq(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$.

But if $\aleph_1<2^{\aleph_0}$, meaning if the Continuum Hypothesis fails, then $\aleph_1<\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Why $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: Do you know how cardinal exponentiation is defined?

Comment: I don't know the exact definition. I think $(2^{\aleph_0})$ should be the cardinal number of the power set of some set.

Comment: [This might be a good start](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89211/how-to-understand-the-definition-of-cardinal-exponentiation/89428#89428), then, or [this place](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57398/how-to-show-abc-abc-for-arbitrary-cardinal-numbers/57439#57439). [This might be a good place to continue, too](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742442/cardinal-arithmetic-basics/742576#742576).

Comment: Thank you so much! I will study them. But how to calculate $({\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}$, if we assume ${\aleph_1} = 2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: Note that in that inequalities I wrote, you can put $\aleph_0$ between $2$ and $\aleph_1$. The result should be apparent now.

Comment: Got it. Interesting:P