# A bijection between $X \times (Y \times Z)$ and $ (X \times Y) \times Z$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone help me prove that 
$$X \times (Y \times Z) \sim (X \times Y) \times Z$$
I know that there is supposed to be a bijection between these two. The first one will contain elements like $(x, (y, z))$ and the second one $((x, y) z)$. I just need some instructions, I believe I can manage on my own from that.

Comment: The way you've written the elements of each set should be really suggestive of what the bijection could be.

Comment: If you only need a bijection between sets (you didn't write what $X,Y, Z$ are), why not $(x,(y,z))\mapsto ((x,y),z)$?

Comment: yeah, but how am i going to proove that that's in fact a bijection?

Comment: Well, you need to prove it's injective and surjective. Here's an element of (X x Y) x Z: ((a, b), c). Can you write down something that is mapped to this element?

Comment: @DietrichBurde A stray * from `**bold formatting**`

Comment: This really is as obvious as it looks.

Answer (score 4):

$$X \times (Y \times Z) = \{(x,(y,z)) \mid x \in X, y \in Y, z \in Z\}$$
$$ (X \times Y) \times Z = \{ ((x,y),z) \mid x \in X, y \in Y, z \in Z \}$$

So consider the maps $(x,(y,z)) \mapsto ((x,y),z)$ and $((x,y),z) \mapsto (x,(y,z))$. One immediately verifies that these are indeed functions and they are clearly inverses, thus bijections.

Comment: Okay guys, thanks a lot