# If $a,b,c$ are cardinals numbers , $a(b+c)=(b+c)a$ is true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I don't know if that property is true for infinite cardinal numbers, but i think is true because the sum of cardinal numbers are a cardinal number and the product of cardinal numbers are conmutative. I'm right?

Comment: See this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131212/overview-of-basic-results-on-cardinal-arithmetic

Comment: You are right, for cardinal numbers, multiplication is commutative. This is easily seen looking at the map $A\times B\to B\times A$, $(a,b)\to (b,a)$ which you can prove is bijective